# Javascript file-conversion inside PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php

We have a file upload inputfield where user upload a zip file. It added to your database and the file size is output in bytes.

Now what i need is i need to convert this to mb, gb, tb... dynamically. so that the file is a human readable format.

We got a Javascript code online which does the conversion. If we combined our php and javascript it loops only once.

Can you help us out. Thanks!

**PHP**

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * from version";
$records=mysql_query($sql);
while($emp=mysql_fetch_array($records)){
    echo $emp['zipfile']."<br />";
    $file = filesize($emp['zipfile']);
    ?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var x = <?php echo $file; ?>;
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = x
function formatSizeUnits(bytes){
if      (bytes>=1073741824) {bytes=(bytes/1073741824).toFixed(2)+' GB';}
else if (bytes>=1048576)    {bytes=(bytes/1048576).toFixed(2)+' MB';}
else if (bytes>=1024)       {bytes=(bytes/1024).toFixed(2)+' KB';}
else if (bytes>1)           {bytes=bytes+' bytes';}
else if (bytes==1)          {bytes=bytes+' byte';}
else                        {bytes='0 byte';}
return bytes;
}
```

**PHP Loop closes**

```
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually convert the filesize to readable format by using PHP itself. The function for this is

```
function formatSizeUnits($bytes)
{
    if ($bytes >= 1073741824)
    {
        $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1073741824, 2) . ' GB';
    }
    elseif ($bytes >= 1048576)
    {
        $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1048576, 2) . ' MB';
    }
    elseif ($bytes >= 1024)
    {
        $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1024, 2) . ' kB';
    }
    elseif ($bytes > 1)
    {
        $bytes = $bytes . ' bytes';
    }
    elseif ($bytes == 1)
    {
        $bytes = $bytes . ' byte';
    }
    else
    {
        $bytes = '0 bytes';
    }

    return $bytes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Sorry for the delay, we got caught up in another thing.